# Compare value inside of use-deep-compare-effect

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, use-effect, use-ref

This is a part of `use-deep-compare-effect` source code

```js
export function useDeepCompareMemoize<T>(value: T) {
  const ref = React.useRef<T>(value)
  const signalRef = React.useRef<number>(0)

  if (!deepEqual(value, ref.current)) {
    ref.current = value
    signalRef.current += 1
  }

  // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  return React.useMemo(() => ref.current, [signalRef.current])
}
```

In source code, compare the values like this.

```js
export function useDeepCompareMemoize<T>(value: T) {
  const ref = React.useRef<T>(value)
  ...
}
```

```js
  ...
  if (!deepEqual(value, ref.current)) {
  ...
```

`deepEqual` is a function that compares whether two parameters are deep equivalent.

I expect `deepEqual(value, ref.current)` to return always true. But it is not.

Why does this code work correctly?

Comment: Not entirely sure, did you find out?

Comment: No, I didn't. I'm just guessing that is related to reference of object